# BPF tail call not called

Tags: c, go, linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

In the following code BPF program `tail_prog` is not getting tail called from `main_prog`:

```
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") jump_table = {
   .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_PROG_ARRAY,
   .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
   .value_size = sizeof(__u32),
   .max_entries = 8,
};

SEC("xdp")
int main_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    bpf_printk("Making tail call");
    bpf_tail_call(ctx, &jump_table, 0);

    return XDP_PASS;
}

SEC("xdp_1")
int tail_prog(struct xdp_md *ctx) {
    bpf_printk("Inside tail call");

    return XDP_PASS;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

I observe only the print in `main_prog` is printed.

I'm loading the BPF programs using [Cilium's eBPF Go package](https://github.com/cilium/ebpf). Here's the code for loading the programs and maps:

```
type BpfObjects struct {
    MainProg *ebpf.Program  `ebpf:"main_prog"`
    TailProg *ebpf.Program  `ebpf:"tail_prog"`
    JumpTable *ebpf.Map     `ebpf:"jump_table"`
}

    var objects BpfObjects

    spec, err := ebpf.LoadCollectionSpec("prog.o")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("ebpf.LoadCollectionSpec", err)
    }

    if err := spec.LoadAndAssign(&objects, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("ebpf.LoadAndAssign", err)
    }

    objects.JumpTable.Update(0, objects.TailProg.FD(), ebpf.UpdateAny)
```

According to [this](https://docs.cilium.io/en/v1.10/bpf/#tail-calls), the jump table has be initialized from user space, which is what I think the last line above is supposed to do. However, I don't see any difference whether that line is there or not.

Comment: You could do two things to help debug this: 1) You can check with bpftool if the prog array map actually contains the entry you wrote from userspace. 2) You can add a `bpf_printk` statement after the tail call to check if it is taken; the `bpf_printk` should only be executed if the tail call failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't looking at the error returned from the `Update` function: `Update can't marshal key: encoding int: binary.Write: invalid type int`. Therefore, the program array map was not updated. I changed to the following:

```
    err = objects.JumpTable.Update(uint32(0), uint32(objects.CopyHttpHostnameProg.FD()), ebpf.UpdateAny)

    if err != nil {
        println("Update", err.Error())
    }
```

If you pass `0` as the key, the size of the key is 8 bytes, which is why you have to do `uint32(0)`, which matches the map's definition. Now the tail calls succeed.